# Why multiple packages are not working in Struts 2?

Tags: java, json, xml, struts2

**This is my `struts.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts 
Configuration 2.3//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
<struts>
<include file="struts-test.xml"></include>
<include file="struts-data.xml"></include>
<include file="struts-empty.xml"></include>
</struts>
```

**This is my `struts-data.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts 
Configuration 2.3//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<package name="default" namespace="/data" extends="json-default">
<action name="getData" class="jsonResponse"> 
<result type="json" />
</action>
</package>
</struts>
```

**This is my `struts-test.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts 
Configuration 2.3//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
<struts>
<package name="default" namespace="/test" extends="struts-default">
<action name="getTest" class="TestClass"> 
<result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
</action>
</package>
</struts>
```

**This is my `struts-empty.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts 
Configuration 2.3//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
<struts>
<package name="default" namespace="/empty" extends="struts-default">
<action name="getEmpty" class="EmptyClass"> 
<result name="success">/empty.jsp</result>
</action>
</package>
</struts>
```

In the above code first include file in `struts.xml` only working
Like `struts-test.xml` is working. If I change the order like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts 
Configuration 2.3//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
<struts>
<include file="struts-data.xml"></include>
<include file="struts-test.xml"></include>
<include file="struts-empty.xml"></include>
</struts>
```

Then `struts-data.xml` file only working.

Why this is happening? Any solution?

**I am getting this `Exception`:**

```
SEVERE: Could not find action or result
/strutsJSON/data/getData.action
There is no Action mapped for action name getData. - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:185)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:63)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:37)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:565)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:81)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2555)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2544)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I think the order is important in struts, if the files are related

Comment: In my case the files are not related to each other

Answer (score 0):

The tag `<include>` is self-closed, i.e. should not have a body.

```
<include file="struts-test.xml"/>
<include file="struts-data.xml"/>
<include file="struts-empty.xml"/>
```